# I have accidently revealed my Firebase project credentials and someone started mining crypto on it. How attack was look like?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have forgot to add to gitignore file, which included:

```
{
  "type": 
  "project_id": ,
  "private_key_id": 
  "private_key":
  "client_email": 
  "client_id": 
  "auth_uri": 
  "token_uri": 
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
  "client_x509_cert_url": 
}
```

and on the same day someone used my project to create a VMs and mine crypto (as google said).
How is it possible that someone used my project? I thought that the attacker also needs Firebase credentials to do some harm. I didn't find any suspicious behavior on the google account used to login into firebase, so maybe attacker had access to my computer (?).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a [JSON Key file for a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys), depending on the permissions  given to such account it can be used to  create other resources  including VMs. That is the reason why is best practice to use principle of least privilege, check: [Least privilege for Cloud Functions using Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/least-privilege-for-cloud-functions-using-cloud-iam)

Comment: thanks, but I know all of this. The question is how attack was looked like? How was he able to log in into firebase? I guess he needed to log in, because I don't know another way to add such a feature as VMs.